# How to prevent aborting in terminate handler depending of exception class

Tags: c++

I set the new terminate handler function with call:

```
std::set_terminate(TerminateHandler);
```

Terminate handler looks like this:

```
void TerminateHandler()
{
    std::exception_ptr exptr = std::current_exception();
    bool abort = true;
    if(exptr != nullptr)
    {
        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception(exptr);
        }
        catch(SoftMyException& ex){
            std::cout << "Soft my exception";
            abort = false;
        }
        catch(std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << "Standard exception";
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            std::cout << "Terminated due to unknown exception";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Terminated due to unknown reason";
    }

    if(abort)
    {
        std::abort();
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Not abort";
    }
}
```

These custom exceptions are set in the shared library and main program. I want to continue the work when SoftException arrives. SoftMyException class is defined like:

```
class SoftMyException : public std::exception{};
```

My program works well but still aborting event abort is not called.

Is here any option to call some function for restart the state inside terminate handler and continue with work without aborting depending of exception class?

Comment: So you're trying to catch exceptions without catching them? Why doesn't the normal try/catch approach work for your soft exceptions?

Comment: That looks like a terrible idea/design. Why do you want to handle exceptions in the terminate handler? What actual problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: It works well but If my external library throws an exception, then I want to catch that in the main program.  I want to catch all exceptions in one place. I don't want to use try catch in every position.

Comment: My main program acts like a core program that has multiple shared libraries. Every library is independent and doesn't know for other libraries. The output of one library is the input of another one.  If something goes wrong in one library that throw exception and the main program know it must restart the state or abort the program, depending of the error. If I return the success of the function, then I must change all the libraries about the approach and return. Also are a lot of places to need to use try catch principle.

Comment: Errors (including exceptions) should be handled as close to the point of the error as possible. If it is possible to handle the error at all. By putting all your error handling in a single place makes it harder or perhaps even impossible to recover from recoverable errors, and you also loose context making it very hard to understand and maintain your code (especially if some exceptions could be thrown from multiple locations).

Comment: `want to continue the work when SoftException arrives` Then catch the expection near your work, you can't "go back" from terminating back to the code (well, at least without spaghetti code). `the main program know it must restart the state or abort the program, depending of the error` Then write a separate program that works as an orchestrator for these other programs and implement communication between them.

Comment: These comments open my eyes and look again at all the code design I have. All "Soft" exceptions I must handle nearest the work, and unknown exceptions I handle in terminate handler. Thank you, guys.